# dock Soft Input Panel Windows CE6

Tags: c, windows-ce

I want to dock the SIP-Soft Input Panel- so it cannot allow to drag to different location on Windows CE screen.  So I try this, but not working.

```
SIPINFO sip;
memset(&sip,0,sizeof(sip));
sip.cbSize=sizeof(SIPINFO);
BOOL bRes = SipGetInfo(&sip);
if ( bRes )
{
   //sip.fdwFlags = SIPF_ON|SIPF_DOCKED;//not working
   sip.fdwFlags = SIPF_DOCKED;
   SipSetInfo(&sip);
}
```

thanks.

- [`SipGetInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa453745.aspx) (MSDN)
- [`SIPINFO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa931236.aspx) (MSDN)

Comment: You should read the description of a tag before you use it. Most of the world knows SIP as the "Session Initiation Protocol", not some obscure Windows CE "software-based input panel".

Comment: You might want to check the result of `SipSetInfo`.

Comment: After calling SipGetInfo() it returns 1 rather 0, next I call GetLastError() and it returns 6 which is handle invalid.  I am not sure now..